# Thymeleaf Template Not Posting Body

Tags: java, spring-mvc, input, thymeleaf

My thymeleaf form is not picking up the input longUrl. When I run the application on debug, it hits the post request below with "". How can I make it pick up the form input and send it over in the body?

[image]

[image]

**Thymeleaf Form:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" th:action="@{create_short_url_thymeleaf}">
    <h1>Hit Enter to Shorten Your Long Url</h1>
        <input type="text" th:name="longUrl"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Even when I try to manually populate the value, it still doesn't make it into the controller

```
<input type="text" name="longUrl" value="somelongurl"/>
```

**Controller Code**:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class UrlShorteningController {

    @GetMapping("/create_short_url")
    public String newShortUrl(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("longUrl",
            "");
        return "some-form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/create_short_url_thymeleaf")
    ResponseEntity<String> newShortUrlFromThymeleaf(@ModelAttribute String longUrl) {
        // Running the application on debug, I make it here, but the longUrl is empty.
       ....
    }
```

Comment: There is no Thymeleaf being used in `th:name="longUrl"` - you can just use `name="longUrl"`.

Comment: Just tried that - it's still coming through as the empty string

Comment: As a test (i.e. a guess), if you change your form submission to use a submit button attached to the form - does that make a difference, vs. your implicit submit?

Comment: Sadly doesn't help!

Answer (score 0):

try to replace 
`th:action="@{create_short_url_thymeleaf}` with

```
th:action="@{/create_short_url_thymeleaf}
```

Comment: That doesn't help, unfortunately. The problem is that the body data (longUrl) isn't sending. It's making into the endpoint just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I solved it. I needed to swap that @ModelMapper annotation for a @RequestBody and now it works.